# Disable or Enable Menu items programatically from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to disable or enable my menu bar for users from database, i have done for parent menu items, but i also want to disable or enable the child menu items, here is my code

```
StrSql = "Select serial_no,optionName,MenuID from [User_" + Session["UserEmail"] + "]";

StrSql = StrSql + " Order By serial_no";

DataSet rs = (DataSet)MethodClass.ConnectionToQuery(StrSql);

if (rs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (i = 0; i < MnuUserManagement.Items.Count; i++)
    {

        StrOpt = MnuUserManagement.Items[i].Text.ToString();

        if (StrOpt != "-" || StrOpt == "")
        {
            for (j = 0; j < rs.Tables[0].Rows.Count ; j++)
            {

                if (StrOpt == rs.Tables[0].Rows[j]["optionName"].ToString())
                {
                    MnuUserManagement.Items[i].Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please show your DB Table structure for creating menu? And some markup too..! Please refer this:http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Multilevel-Dynamic-CSS3-Dropdown-Menu-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

StrSql = "Select serial_no,optionName,MenuID from [User_" + Session["UserEmail"] + "]";
              StrSql = StrSql + " Order By serial_no";
              DataSet rsmenu = (DataSet)MethodClass.ConnectionToQuery(StrSql);
              if (rsmenu.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
              {

```
              for (var i = 0; i < rsmenu.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
              {
                  foreach (MenuItem item in MnuUserManagement.Items)
                  {
       if (item.Text == rsmenu.Tables[0].Rows[i]["optionName"].ToString())
                      {
                          item.Enabled = true;
```

//Here i start a new dataset for child menu item
StrSql = "Select serial_no,optionName,MenuID from [User_" + Session["UserEmail"]+ "]";
            StrSql = StrSql + " Order By serial_no";
            DataSet rs = (DataSet)MethodClass.ConnectionToQuery(StrSql);

```
        if (rs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < rs.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                foreach (MenuItem childItem in item.ChildItems)
                {
          if (childItem.Text == rs.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Optionname"].ToString())
                    {
                        childItem.Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
                      }
                  }
              }

          }
```